# Discord.js making an image using canvas throws an error Canvas.createCanvas is not a function

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

I'm trying to make an image using canvas but i get error "Canvas.createCanvas is not a function" in doing so

```js
const { Canvas, Image } = require('canvas');

module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    description: 'avatar',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./yellow.png');
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }));

        ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 0, 200, canvas.height);

        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'test.png');

        channel.send(attachment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```js
const Canvas = require("canvas");
```

not

```
const { Canvas, Image } = require('canvas');
```

You also don't need to import Image because you are not using it.